# Disable InfoWindowClick on 1 icon on google map android v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I cannot find a way to disable infowindowclick on an single icon. Is there a way to do this? I have a single icon that I create that marks my location. I then have many other markers, but this one that I have created for my location I would like to disable the infowindowclick on, however, I would like to leave it for the rest.

Is there an ID of a sort that will always be for my location icon that I can use in a if else or switch case?

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker. check Info window click events it it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan I've searched through here and haven't found a solution... hence the SO question... Do you see something I am missing there?

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        LatLng isMyLatLng = marker.getPosition();

        if(isMyLatLng.longitude== yourLongitude && isMyLatLng.latitude == yourLatitude ){
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        }else{
            // write your code here for  show InfoWindow other point
        }
}
```

Comment: Good, yes... as long as I don't update my lat/lon once I get the lat/lon I'd be good. I have a class that "if" a better lat/lon is found it will update it... I might have to disable that.